# Disabled right-click, three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, right-click

I made a website using `react.js` but somewhere in the process, the right-click was disabled. I noticed that first when I used `three.js` to add a 3d model as a `glb` file. I don't have much experience with `three.js` but I could add the model to the website. The only problem was when I clicked on the right, instead of opening the tab I was moving the model. Because of this, I removed all the code that loads and displays the model, but the problem doesn't solve. What can I do now? I thought I installed something with `three.js` that disabled right-click. I checked my browser settings, and all the code but didn't find anything that can cause this. Any idea?

Comment: If you inspect your page in the browser, in Chrome's DevTools under the tab Elements, you have another tab to the right called "Event Listeners" - are there anything unexpected there under "click" or "contextmenu" ?

Comment: Thank you it helped, but only when I remove the three.js. I deleted the 'contextmenu' from event listeners. I want to try it with the model, and do the same, I move the model with right click and do not open the tab.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I decided to comment out all the code and uncomment it line by line to find the culprit. Surprisingly, the line causing this issue is

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, canvas.width / canvas.height,0.1, 1000 );
```

I'm not sure why yet, but I'm 100% sure that line is the problem.
I just installed an extension that allows me to enable right click. Not ideal but I don't know what else to do.